# Creating a Google search box using HTML form

Tags: html, forms, google-search

So I am trying to insert a search form on my website that will redirect the user with their query to Google Search.

I used to be able to do this using:

```html
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en-GB&source=hp&q=">
  <div id="gform">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"></label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
    <input type="submit" class="btn fa-input" value="&#xf002;" style="font-family: FontAwesome;">
  </div>
</form>
```

However, this no longer works. I'm guessing this is because Google have changed the search URL, but I am unable to replicate this effect by using Google's current URL.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Well it works if pasted into a browser.  What you have will not work within a frame.  Have you looked in the F12 error console? What do you see when you submit the form?

Comment: fixed by changing name to q

Comment: @Lukas_T: If you have solved your problem, please add it as an answer.

Comment: It would be REAL nice if search engines didn't offer the incorrect question as a suggested answer, this is why I hate ML because in the end it assumes and never ascertains correctly. A customer was having this issue with this particular question showing as the answer body in some search engine, I keep having to explain to people that the search engines aren't intelligent they just dole out whatever value they find first in a page and use that as an "answer". Someone please stop thinking ML is AI, it's not and when misused as it often is, makes more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 5):

Hi all it seems I have solved the problem myself

```html
<div id="gform">
  <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"></label>
  <input type="text" value="" name="q" id="s">
  <input type="submit" class="btn fa-input" value="&#xf002;" style="font-family: FontAwesome;"> 
</div>
```

The key here that resolved my issue is `name="q"`. This is what you need to make google search work; basically this is because google expects `q` as the name

Comment: i would comment here that even if you answered your own question, you should still mark it as an answer for the future viewers to clearly see that this is a valid answer.

Comment: Yes, and even though it isn't the OP's fault, probably change the question to the correct code, since search engines are now being dumb and showcasing the incorrect item as being the "answer". I have clients who rely too much on GA and ML, and it in turn makes me have to repeat myself a million times that ML is not AI, it doesn't actually know answers it guesses. Unfortunately, those guesses are making my work a real pain.

Answer (score 5):

This snippet creates a simple google search box

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q"/>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have solved you problem very easily.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Google Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).