# I want to append my own text beforehand to a google search in html

Tags: html, search, text, append

This explains how to add a search bar in html: [Creating a Google search box using HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305582/creating-a-google-search-box-using-html-form/57687520?noredirect=1#comment101820118_57687520)

What if we want to previously append some of our own text to the search? for example,

when I input a text into the search, google should search for "hotels at input-text"

This creates the search bar:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en-GB&source=hp&+q=">
  <div id="gform">
  <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"></label>
  <input type="text" value="" name="q" id="s">
  <input type="submit" class="btn fa-input" value="&#xf002;" style="font-family: FontAwesome;"> 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You'll be needing some javascript, google Submit event listener.

Comment: Im currently learning hmtl and css only. No way to do with only these ?

Comment: Well no. HTML is for layout, it's a `markup` language. CSS is for styling `Cascading Style Sheets`. Javascript is used for DOM manipulation and event handling. If you want to hijack a form (i.e. do something other than a raw submit of the form), you need to latch on to the submit event, prevent the default action, prepend your text to the input and then fire the submit event. This can only be done with JS.